# Why is my byte array returned from fread smaller than the number of bytes in the file itself when it includes unicode special symbols?

Tags: matlab, unicode, character-encoding, xml-parsing

I am having some trouble with encoding special characters and parsing XML in a big complex project in Matlab. I have isolated the problem and though I still don't know how to solve it, I think it is related to this question.

Consider the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
    <desc>
        <channels>
            <channel>
                <label>accZ</label>
                <unit>mg₀</unit>
                <type>ACC</type>
            </channel>
        </channels>
    </desc>
</info>
```

Assuming Unix style line endings, this file contains 175 bytes of data. Indeed that is what it says when I open it in Notepad++. Now I have an XML parsing function that I copied almost exactly from Mathworks' explanation of how to parse XML in Matlab (https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlread.html). This function works very well and is not the issue, it is included only for completeness' sake:

```
% parse a simplified (attribute-free) subset of XML into a MATLAB struct
function result = parse_xml_struct(str)
import org.xml.sax.InputSource
import javax.xml.parsers.*
import java.io.*
tmp = InputSource();
tmp.setCharacterStream(StringReader(str));
result = parseChildNodes(xmlread(tmp));

% this is part of xml2struct (slightly simplified)
    function [children,ptext] = parseChildNodes(theNode)
        % Recurse over node children.
        children = struct;
        ptext = [];
        if theNode.hasChildNodes
            childNodes = theNode.getChildNodes;
            numChildNodes = childNodes.getLength;
            for count = 1:numChildNodes
                theChild = childNodes.item(count-1);
                [text,name,childs] = getNodeData(theChild);
                if (~strcmp(name,'#text') && ~strcmp(name,'#comment'))
                    if (isfield(children,name))
                        if (~iscell(children.(name)))
                            children.(name) = {children.(name)}; end
                        index = length(children.(name))+1;
                        children.(name){index} = childs;
                        if(~isempty(text))
                            children.(name){index} = text; end
                    else
                        children.(name) = childs;
                        if(~isempty(text))
                            children.(name) = text; end
                    end
                elseif (strcmp(name,'#text'))
                    if (~isempty(regexprep(text,'[\s]*','')))
                        if (isempty(ptext))
                            ptext = text;
                        else
                            ptext = [ptext text];
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

% this is part of xml2struct (slightly simplified)
    function [text,name,childs] = getNodeData(theNode)
        % Create structure of node info.
        name = char(theNode.getNodeName);
        if ~isvarname(name)
            name = regexprep(name,'[-]','_dash_');
            name = regexprep(name,'[:]','_colon_');
            name = regexprep(name,'[.]','_dot_');
        end
        [childs,text] = parseChildNodes(theNode);
        if (isempty(fieldnames(childs)))
            try
                text = char(theNode.getData);
            catch
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Now to test it:

```
finfo = dir('xml_example');
sz = finfo.bytes
fid = fopen('xml_example', 'r', 'ieee-le.l64');
data = fread(fid, sz, '*char');
data_size = size(data)
h = parse_xml_struct(data);
unit = h.info.desc.channels.channel.unit
```

and the output:

```
sz =

   175


data_size =

   173     1


unit =

    'mg₀'
```

So somehow I end up with the right output, but lost 2 bytes along the way. I do not understand why this is happening.

And just to prove to myself that it is the little subscript 'o' that is causing the discrepancy between the size of the file and the number of bytes in my `data` array, I delete it from the XML file and get the following:

```
sz =

   172


data_size =

   172     1


unit =

    'mg'
```

Still the right output for the xml label and now the file size and the byte array size match. What's the deal?

**Update**

Furthermore, if I run the same test on a symbol that is 2-bytes long, I still get the compression phenomenon.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
    <desc>
        <channels>
            <channel>
                <label>ωX</label>
                <unit>mrad/s</unit>
                <type>AUX</type>
            </channel>
        </channels>
    </desc>
</info>
```

Output:

```
sz =

   175


data_size =

   174     1


unit =

'ωX'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `₀` symbol is three bytes long with a UTF-8 encoding (`0xE2 0x82 0x80`). And internal to MATLAB, it's actually two bytes due to a [UTF-16 encoding](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/unicode-and-ascii-values.html) (`0x80 0x20` little-endian).

However, since a [`precision` of `*char`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html#btp1twt-1-precision) was given to `fread`, the returned data is [returned as a `char` array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html#btp1twt-1-A)<sup>1</sup>. And to a `char` array, regardless of the underlying encoding, `₀` is simply a single character when considering its [`size`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html#bvfgzsm-1-sz):

> If `A` is a character vector of type `char`, then `size` returns the row vector `[1 M]` where `M` is the number of characters.

<sup>1</sup> I'm assuming the strong assertion of matching matrix size from `fread` if `sizeA` is given (per the documentation) is only valid for numeric data since, as may be evident above, byte count and character count are not necessarily one-to-one.

Comment: Oh, I see, the array is now chars, not bytes.

Comment: The thing I don't understand, though, is how Matlab knows that 'o' is three bytes long when char is (by definition) 2. This is a problem when reading from a binary file, which is what I want to do. How do I know how to split up the bytes ahead of time? Clearly Matlab has some understanding of how to do this.

Comment: @dmedine Since `encodingIn` wasn't specified, ["`fopen` uses auto character-set detection to determine the encoding"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#btrnibn-1-encodingIn). And whatever algorithm MATLAB uses determined the encoding to be UTF-8. The [UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding) specifies how many bytes to read for a symbol. In this case, because the first four bits of the `0xE2` byte are "1110", the encoding says to read three bytes (because three "1"s).

Comment: @dmedine Minor note: I believe `char` is defined to be one byte not two.

Comment: The three bytes thing now makes sense (I didn't know that) but actually, I am specifying the encoding at fopen. It is 'ieee-le.l64'. Also, `char` is definitely 2 bytes. I just checked: `c=char('c'); whos c` returns `2` under `Bytes`. In any case something funny is happening when matlab decides to turn a 3 byte symbol into a 2 byte char and I still don't understand how to gain control over this.

Comment: @dmedine The `ieee-le.l64` is the [`machinefmt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#btrnibn-1-machinefmt) that specifies the endianness and block size (long versus int, I assume); I think this is primarily for integer data in binary files.  The `encodingIn` comes after the `machinefmt`.  And yes, MATLAB indeed stores characters in a two-byte, UTF-16 encoding; I was referring to the C data type size of one byte.  All of that said, without a more specific goal (which likely lies outside the scope of this question), I'm unsure of how to help you proceed beyond this explanation.

Comment: This is an XML file - why do you want to read it as binary instead of as text? Text is the correct way to handle it. There's nothing funny going on here: you're reading in UTF-8 text data, which is a variable-length encoding (different characters are represented with different numbers of bytes), and Matlab is converting it to UTF-16, a single-width encoding where any character (in the BMP) is represented with a single 2-byte code unit (a Matlab `char`) element. `size()` returns the number of array elements in a Matlab array, not number of bytes.

Comment: If you really want to read the data in as bytes instead of text, do `fread(..., '*uint8')` instead of `fread(..., '*char')`. `*char` means to read the input as text and do transcoding.

Comment: "I'm assuming the strong assertion of matching matrix size from fread if sizeA is given is only valid for numeric data since..." - not quite. `sizeA` is the (maximum) number of output elements (characters, in this case) for `fread` to read. It'll match the size of the returned array; it's the relationship between `sizeA` and the number of input bytes read that is variable. (Caveat: Non-BMP Unicode characters requiring UTF-16 surrogate pairs may break this relationship; I dunno.)

Comment: Oh: and the fact that you're using `StringReader(str)`, instead of a `Reader(ByteArrayInputStream(...))` or something like that, means that you do want this data as text, not binary. So this is all working fine, and as designed.

Comment: @AndrewJanke This is a scaled down version from a larger project. In real life the xml snippets are interspersed with binary data and I have to read it out section by section. There, I was getting weird results for the multi-byte characters. The xml file is a trivial example meant to isolate my problem. Incidentally, I fixed the problem in my non-trivial program  by using exactly what you ended up suggesting: `fread(..., '*uint8')`. In case you are interested: https://github.com/xdf-modules/xdf-Matlab/pull/11